# iPhone 6s Plus Portrait is using the Landscape Launch Image

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I built my Cordova & Ionic iPhone app and launched it on my iPhone 6s+. It used the 6+ (Retina HD 5.5") landscape launch image instead of the 6+ portrait launch image. In the general settings, I have device orientation set to portrait only. Why would it be using the landscape image for portrait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splash images we received for the 6s/6s+ were the incorrect sizes. Xcode would then default to the landscape since it was there. Once we put the correct sized portrait splash images everything was okay.